# Pagination (Startafter) is not working in firestore and Angular 9 App

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

On page load I'm getting the data of 15 records, after scrolling down I can able to call the API but it's returning empty array.(I have total 40 records in my firestore db).

```
// Service.ts
getUsers(config: any) {
    return this.firestore
    .collection(
      'users',
      ref => ref
      .where('country', '==', 'India')
      .orderBy('lastlogin')
      .startAfter(config.page * config.limit)
      .limit(config.limit)
    )
    .snapshotChanges();
  }

// Component

getUsers() {
    this.loader = true;
    this.userService.getUsers(this.config).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.loader = false;
      const data = res.map((e: any) => ({
        id: e.payload.doc.id,
        ...e.payload.doc.data()
      }));
      this.usersCollection = this.usersCollection.concat(data);
    });

// Infinite Scroll
onScroll() {
    this.config.page += 1;
    this.getUsers();
  }
```

### My Solution

Only problem is first time lastVisible have no data, have to set to 0.

```
getUsers(config: any, lastVisible) {
    const { doc } = lastVisible.payload ? lastVisible.payload : { doc: 0}
    return this.firestore
    .collection(
      'users',
      ref => ref
      .where('country', '==', 'India')
      .orderBy('lastlogin')
      .startAfter(doc)
      .limit(config.limit)
    )
    .snapshotChanges();
  }

// Component

getUsers() {
    this.loader = true;
    this.userService.getUsers(this.config, this.lastVisible).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.loader = false;
      this.lastVisible = res[res.length - 1];
      const data = res.map((e: any) => ({
        id: e.payload.doc.id,
        ...e.payload.doc.data()
      }));
      this.usersCollection = this.usersCollection.concat(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore pagination does not work based on a numeric offset, but is based on so-called cursors/anchor document. From the documentation on [`startAfter`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#startafter):

> Creates and returns a new Query that starts after the provided document (exclusive). The starting position is relative to the order of the query. The document must contain all of the fields provided in the orderBy of this query.

So your call:

```
 .startAfter(config.page * config.limit)
```

Tries to start after the document instance `config.page * config.limit`. Since this is not a document snapshot/reference but a number, it doesn't know what document to start after, so it returns nothing.

Instead of passing a numeric offset, you'll need to remember the last document snapshot of the current results and pass that into `startAfter`.

I highly recommend reading the documentation on [paginating data with query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).

Comment: I'm sending the last snapshot data, throwing error (I'm not getting it what format need to send). what ever response getting from firestore DB, I took last record and sending it next time

Sample response
payload: {type: "added", doc: n, oldIndex: -1, newIndex: 9}
type: "added"

Error: ERROR FirebaseError: Function Query.startAfter() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom n object (found in field payload.doc)

Comment: You should just be able to pass in the `DocumentSnapshot` of the last document. Other formats are possible, but typically lead to more problems. If you're having a hard time making that work, can you edit your question to show what you've done?

Comment: I'm getting the response now, I have to send last item "doc" object to startafter.

lastVisible = {
    payload: {
      doc: {}
    }
  };